# Weblogic APP-INF classloading with JSF + RichFaces + CDI + EJB

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I´m having classloading issues in Weblogic 10.3.6.0.

I put all library JARs inside APP-INF/lib folder so both WAR packages and EJB JAR packages can see CDI packages, but now RichFaces can´t see JSF classes.

RichFaces is using Thread Context classloader to find JSF, but the Thread Context classloader can´t see packages inside APP-INF/lib for some reason.

I´m missing something regarding APP-INF/lib classloader, EJB classloader, WAR classloader and Thread Context classloader.

Comment: Weblogic 10.3.6 does not support CDI, only 12c does.

Comment: Natively, no. But you can add Weld to it. Anyway, the issue is between Thread Context classloader and APP-INF/lib packages.

Comment: Found a work around by customizing classloader hierarchy in weblogic-application.xml. I still wonder why Thread Context classloader can´t see APP-INF/lib packages with default settings.

Comment: I've tried to do that long time ago, but did not succeed. There were issues with annotations processing. Anyways post an answer if you will find it.